# how to find bitwise AND operations value using school math

Tags: math

Is there any way to find the bitwise operations value in manual calculation. such as school math without binary calculations.... for example c=a&b;
to find the results of c I need some elementary school math calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that a = 12 and b = 7.  We're using small numbers to illustrate the process.

Write out the values in binary bits

```
12 - 1100
 7 - 0111
     ----
     0100
```

If a column has all 1's (ones), bring the 1 down as the answer.  Otherwise, the answer is 0 (zero).

Binary 0100 = decimal 4.

So 12 & 7 = 4.

If you are using bigger numbers, group the bits in groups of 4 to make it easier to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal, then binary and to convert the binary answer back to hexadecimal and then decimal.

Comment: Actually binary 0100 is decimal 4 as far as I know...

Comment: @Blablablaster: Thanks for the correction.  That's what I get for doing binary conversions in my head.

Comment: But isn’t that exactly the kind of binary operations that is not wanted according to the question?

Comment: actually I need some decimal calculation... is there any way?

Comment: @Joachim Breitner: I don't know of any way to do bit logical operations without using bits.  If anyone does know, go ahead and answer.

Comment: Then the answer would be „no“, wouldn’t it?

Comment: I think the answer is no, not sure as well how to answer this as we need to convert it to binary first. Have a look at this site, it explains and has a calculator as well: http://www.bitwiseoperatorcalculator.com